# Barycenter with a negative weight

Tags: affine-geometry

My question is about the barycenter. Given an affine space $(A,V)$, being $A$ a set and $V$ a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space, for $\{p_1,\dots,p_k\}$ and *weights* $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k \in \mathbb{R}$, you define the *barycenter* as the element $g \in A$ such that $$\alpha_1\vec{gp_1}+\cdots+\alpha_k\vec{gp_k} = \vec{0}.$$

Now, in the real affine plane $(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$, if you want to **draw** the barycenter of $\{a,b,c\}$, vertices of an equilateral triangle, with weights $\{-1,2,3\}$, what you have?

My try:

Let $g'$ the barycenter of $\{b,c\}$ with weights $2,3$, so $2\vec{g'b}+3\vec{g'c} = \vec{0}$. Then $2\vec{g'b}=3\vec{cg'}$.

[image: ------]

Now, $g$ the barycenter of $\{g',a\}$ with weights $\{3+2,-1\}$ satisfies $-\vec{ga}+5\vec{gg'}=\vec{0}$. Therefore $\vec{ga}=5\vec{gg'}$.

I think the next picture is wrong (because the orientation of vectors?):

[image]

So, **how you can draw** this barycenter?

What a **negative weight means** (even physic interpretation)?

Is there exist **a method** to draw/calculate negative weights?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can think to the negative weight $-w_i$ applied at $\vec p_i$ as a positive weight $w_i$ applied at $-\vec p_i$.

Comment: But the elements of $A$ don't have sign. You have $a \in A$, don´t exist $-a$.

Comment: @user183002 I've understood that $a$ is a location with negative weight $-1$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, so a location don´t have sing, only vectors have it.